# Is it possible to connect to java from a firefox extension in the way described below

Tags: java, javascript, firefox-addon

My objective is to:

Use Firefox to take a series of screendump images and save on the local Filesystem with a reference.

also via my custom extension send a reference to a java program that performs the ftp to a remote server.

This is pretty intimidating 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/LiveConnect_Overview

Is it possible?
Can you see any potential problems or things Id need to consider?
(I'm aware of file system problems but its for local use only)
Are there any tutorials / references that might be handy?

Ive tried linking to java but hit problems using my own classes Im getting a class not found exception when I try

JS:

`var myObj = new Packages.message();`

Java file:

```
public class Message {
    private String message;

    public Message()
    {
        this.message = "Hello";
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

not using a package java side.

Just trying to run a quick test to see if it is viable and under time pressure from those above so just wanted to see if it was a worthwhile time investment or a dead end

Comment: `Are there any tutorials / references that might be handy?` What about the guide you linked? This should get you started.

Comment: You have already pointed to the best JavaScript reference at the Internet. Go try it, and come back when you've got specific questions.

Comment: @Rob W I'm cool with the javascript it just won't talk to the java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider this Java tutorial instead: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/liveconnect-docs-349790.html.

What Java version are you using? Is your message class an object inside Java applet?